# How can I extract elements of a list?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, confidence-interval

I am trying to select the upper 95% CI of this data to report in another output. I want to do something like `ci$a[upper]` but that's not working. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

```
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(10)
df <- data.frame(a, b)
ci <- map(df, function (x) CI(x, ci=.95))
```

The output of `ci` is:

```
$a
      upper        mean       lower 
 1.27519623  0.62227924 -0.03063774 

$b
     upper       mean      lower 
 0.4755253 -0.1364711 -0.7484675
```

I want to do

```
paste("The mean of a is ",ci$a[upper],sep="")
```

Comment: `mean(ci$a)`...

Comment: You just need to enclose `upper` in quotes: `paste("The mean of a is ",ci$a["upper"],sep="")`.